# Checkbox Value in VBscript/HTML

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

I have created a simple form that sends data to an Excel file with an array. 
Everything works great except check boxes. What I would like is if the checkbox is "checked" it will post its value into the Excel document. Currently the value assigned for the box (checked) is always pasted no matter if it is checked or not. I am unsure what code is needed for the `arr(6)`.

```html
<script>
  function PrintFunction() {
      window.print();
  }
</script>

<script type="text/vbscript">
  function test()
    dim oApp, oWB, arr
    set oApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oApp.visible=false
    set wb = oApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\(PATH TO DB)\DB.xls",,,,"password")
    redim arr(6)

    arr(0) = Date()
    arr(1) = Form1.text1.Value
    arr(2) = Time()
    arr(3) = Form1.text2.Value
    arr(4) = Form1.text3.Value
    arr(5) = Form1.text4.Value
    arr(6) = Form1.text5.Value  <---Need help with this value

    with wb.sheets("Data").cells(1,1).currentregion
      .offset(.rows.count,0).resize(1).value = arr
    end with
    wb.close true

  x=msgbox("Submitted." ,64, "Thank you.")

    window.close()

  end function
</script>
</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false;"> 
<form name="Form1">
<table border="0" style="width:700px;">
<td>Date:<input value="mm/dd/yyyy" name="text1" type="text" class="inputbox" size="20" />
<tr>
<td>Time:<input value="00:00 AM/PM" name="text2" type="text" class="inputbox" size="20" /></td>
<tr>
<td>Name:<input name="text3" type="text" class="inputbox" size="23"/></td>
<tr>
<td>Location:<input name="text4" type="text" class="inputbox" size="18" /></td>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="text5" value="checked">Checkbox Title</td>
<input type="button" value="Print" class="classname" onclick="PrintFunction()" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="classname" onclick="test()" />
</table>
<br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a text box is "Checked" or "Unchecked". If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like there is another text box on the form whose value you want to copy (though I don't see it in your HTML code; maybe you need to add it?). Something like:

```
If Form1.text5.Checked = True Then
    arr(6) = Form1.text6.Value  'Or .Text
End If
```

Comment: Josh this helped. Thank you. I changed the text6 value back to 5 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. To name a checkbox "test5" is an atrocity. Just see what it did to Josh.
2. This

   ```html
   <html>
    <head>
     <hta:application id = "cbxproblem">
     <script type="text/vbscript">
      function test()
        MsgBox Form1.cbx.checked ' <---Need help with this value
        MsgBox Form1.cbx.value
      end function
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form name="Form1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="cbx" value="pipapo" checked="checked">Checkbox Title
       <hr />
       <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="test()" />
     </form>
    </body>
   </html>
   ```

   is all the code needed to present/discuss your problem. Dragging Excel and the text elements into the question is obfuscation and wasting other people's time.
3. Reading about the [checkbox element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html) and comparing

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="text5" value="checked">
   ```

   vs.

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="cbx" value="pipapo" checked="checked">
   ```

   should make you realize the differences between the **value** and the **checked** attribute.
4. Running the demo code will prove that the **checked** attribute is set to `True` or `False` depending on the user (not) marking/checking the box.
5. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/15/184431.aspx) to understand why

   ```
   If Form1.text5.Checked = True Then ' <-- nonono
   ```

   should be

   ```
   If Form1.text5.Checked Then
   ```

Comment: I appreciate all of the input and examples. 

I'd rather tell someone everything I'm doing so they get the full picture ahead of time. It might be a waste of time to you, but maybe not to others. No reason to be so hostile.